# Heavy image(very large image) loading effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem want to share with you.
So here it is. Imagine I have a very large image and it take a heavy loading when I open my page. Is it possible if I want to have the effect like cut the image to many smaller pieces and merge them one by one while the image is loading(just javascript, jquery, css and html code).

html:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
        <img id="imgHeavy" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLQe4.png" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div id="frameMerge" style="float:left; width: 200px; height:200px; background: #ddd;">
    </div>
</div>
```

So now I want to set the background of my element(#frameMerge) is every single pieces of the image(#imgHeavy) that have been cut when the page is opened.
Please take a look at 2 pictures!

My img:
[image]

My div element:
[image]

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Splitting the image into multiple smaller images that then all have to be loaded via their own HTTP request will not speed things up – quite the opposite. I’d rather see what image optimization is still possible, if using a progressive image format helps, or have a low-res version of the image load first, and then replace it with the full-res version once its loaded.

Comment: Sorry! But your opinion is not what I want. I can resize my image but what I want is use the technique and get the effect as I said. Also I mean just use the only one image, not multiple smaller images. Thanks!

Comment: First part was not opinion, but fact. And with just one image, how would you display “parts” of it before the whole image is loaded …?

Comment: My destination is not a image, It is a div element. How about if you set it's background like this: background: url() Xpx Ypx;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS3 and jquery.

Here is an example for you :

[jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/4nsJE/](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/4nsJE/)

```
;(function( $, window ) {

  var _defaults = {
    x      : 2, // number of tiles in x axis
    y      : 2, // number of tiles in y axis
    random : true, // animate tiles in random order
    speed  : 2000 // time to clear all times
  };

  /**
  * range Get an array of numbers within a range
  * @param min {number} Lowest number in array
  * @param max {number} Highest number in array
  * @param rand {bool} Shuffle array
  * @return {array}
  */
  function range( min, max, rand ) {
    var arr = ( new Array( ++max - min ) )
      .join('.').split('.')
      .map(function( v,i ){ return min + i })
    return rand
      ? arr.map(function( v ) { return [ Math.random(), v ] })
         .sort().map(function( v ) { return v[ 1 ] })
      : arr
  }

  // Prevent css3 transitions on load
  $('body').addClass('css3-preload')
  $( window ).load(function(){ $('body').removeClass('css3-preload') })

  $.fn.sliced = function( options ) {

    var o = $.extend( {}, _defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {

      var $container = $(this);

      /*---------------------------------
       * Make the tiles:
       ---------------------------------*/

      var width = $container.width(),
          height = $container.height(),
          $img = $container.find('img'),
          n_tiles = o.x * o.y,
          tiles = [], $tiles;

      for ( var i = 0; i < n_tiles; i++ ) {
        tiles.push('<div class="tile"/>');
      }

      $tiles = $( tiles.join('') );

      // Hide original image and insert tiles in DOM
      $img.hide().after( $tiles );

      // Set background
      $tiles.css({
        width: width / o.x,
        height: height / o.y,
        backgroundImage: 'url('+ $img.attr('src') +')'
      });

      // Adjust position
      $tiles.each(function() {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        $(this).css( 'backgroundPosition', -pos.left +'px '+ -pos.top +'px' );
      });

      /*---------------------------------
       * Animate the tiles:
       ---------------------------------*/

      var tilesArr = range( 0, n_tiles, o.random ),
          tileSpeed = o.speed / n_tiles; // time to clear a single tile

      // Public method
      $container.on( 'animate', function() {

        tilesArr.forEach(function( tile, i ) {
          setTimeout(function(){
            $tiles.eq( tile ).toggleClass( 'tile-animated' );
          }, i * tileSpeed );
        });

      });

    });

  };

}( jQuery, window ));

$('.sliced').sliced({ x: 6, y: 4, speed: 1000 });

$('button').click(function() {
    $('.sliced').trigger('animate');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functionality of multiple background images provided by css3, but it won't be faster in the end as the data being loaded with multiple pictures is even bigger (header-information of every single file) than with just one. The only difference would be, that you see parts of the image before the rest is loaded. But you can have the same effect if your image is a jpg. So you can use a progressive jpg that will show parts of your image while the rest is still loading.

Comment: A couple of things... Some (even recent) browsers show progressive jpegs all at once when download finishes -- The overhead of loading the image as a serie of tiles is mostly given by the higher load on the server that receives multiple request -- The only good reason to split an image into tiles is when the image is bigger than the viewport (visible area/window) so you want to "lazy-load" each piece only when it enters the viewport subsequently to a scroll or resize of the viewport itself.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can just put an `onload` event on every segment (must be on `<img>` though) that makes it fade in. However, actually splitting the image into segments cannot be done on client side. You will need to either manually split the image beforehand or rely on server side scripting (e.g. php) to do this.

Also, do note that doing this will create quite a lot of overhead depending on the amount of segments you use, since every segment will need to make a new request to the server including downloading the file headers for every image.

Comment: thank you, Sir! But I think it's not so good if touch the server side.